# What are the odds of rolling two number cubes (fair) and getting a sum of 7?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

my answer is $\frac{1}{5}$. but I ran into some resources that the answer should be $\frac{1}{6}$. I understand how they got that answer but word "odds" make me confused. I know the formula for odds probability but it seems it shouldn't be followed in this particular question. What do you think?

Comment: A probability of $1/6$ translates to odds of $5:1$ against.

Comment: so the answer should be 1/6? or 1/5 or 1/5 is not right because it's not the equivalent odds of the probability of the question?

Comment: Odds are written with colons, the odds of it occurring are 5:1 against, which reworded that is to say, for every five times it doesn't occur you would expect that it would have occurred once).  Reworded again, out of six tries, five of those six you get a sum different than 7 and the other one of those six you do get a sum of 7.  All iff these ways of presenting the information mean the same thing in the end, they are merely different ways of expressing it.  The probability is 1/6.  The odds for are 1:5.  The odds against are 5:1.

Comment: That being said, although they all convey the same information, you should write your answer with your audience in mind.  If they explicitly ask for odds, write it as an odds.  If they specifically ask for a probability, write it as a probability.  Just like how if you were asked to find the length of something, if they ask how many meters it is you use a meter stick while if they ask how many feet it is you use a yard stick.  They both convey how long the object is, they just do so in slightly different ways.